# PHP web service returns "403 forbidden" error

Tags: php, web-services, http-status-code-403

I have created a simple web service in PHP and tested on my local XAMPP. When I upload it to my server and test it with the online tools in the following link, it works perfectly. But when I want to call it in PHP or .NET it returns a "forbidden" error . I don't know what I should do or what is really the problem.

Here is my server code:

```
    <?php

require_once 'settings.php';

function SetLocation($MsqType, $DeviceID, $Latitude, $Longitude, $Speed, $Date, $Alarm) {

        $mysqli = new mysqli($_SESSION['DBServer'], $_SESSION['DBUserName'], $_SESSION['DBPassword'], $_SESSION['DBName']);
        if (!$mysqli->connect_errno) {
            $mysqli->query("set character_set_client ='utf8'");
            $mysqli->query("set character_set_results='utf8'");
            $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
            $Result = $mysqli->query(""
                    . "INSERT INTO `tblcarlocation`"
                    . "(`fldmsgtype`, `flddeviceid`, `fldlatitude`, `fldlongitude`, `fldspeed`, `flddate`, `fldalarm`)"
                    . " VALUES "
                    . "('$MsqType','$DeviceID','$Latitude','$Longitude','$Speed','$Date','$Alarm')");
            if ($Result) {
                if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                } else {
                    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                }
                //return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'].':'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].':'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].':'. $ip.':'.$Result;
                return $Result;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
         return $mysqli->connect_errno;;   
        }
    }
$server = new SoapServer('http://www.bitsite.ir/parvaneh/webservice/setlocation.wsdl');

$server->addFunction('SetLocation');

$server->handle();
```

And this is WSDL file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="SetLocation" 
             targetNamespace="urn:SetLocation" 
             xmlns:tns="urn:SetLocation"  
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:SetLocation">
            <xsd:element name="MsgType" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="DeviceID" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Latitude" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Longitude" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Speed" type="xsd:int" />
            <xsd:element name="Date" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="Alarm" type="xsd:int" />            
            <xsd:element name="SetLocation" type="xsd:string" />          
        </xsd:schema>           
    </types>

    <message name="SetLocation">
        <part name="MsgType" type="xsd:int" />
        <part name="DeviceID" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="Latitude" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="Longitude" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="Speed" type="xsd:int" />
        <part name="Date" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="Alarm" type="xsd:int" />  
    </message>

    <message name="SetLocationResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>  

    <portType name="SetLocationPort">
        <operation name="SetLocation">
            <input message="tns:SetLocation" />
            <output message="tns:SetLocationResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="SetLocationBinding" type="tns:SetLocationPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="SetLocation">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:SetLocationAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:SetLocation" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />         
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:SetLocation" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />         
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="SetLocationService">
        <port name="SetLocationPort" binding="tns:SetLocationBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.bitsite.ir/parvaneh/webservice/setlocation.php" />
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

And this is my client code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        test client . <br>

        <?php
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0');

        $options['cache_wsdl'] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;

        try {
            $api = new SoapClient("http://www.bitsite.ir/parvaneh/webservice/setlocation.wsdl");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo($e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>');
            var_dump($e);
        }

        $ar = array(
            'MsgType' => 1,
            'DeviceID' => '1',
            'Latitude' => '1',
            'Longitude' => '1',
            'Speed' => 1,
            'Date' => '1',
            'Alarm' => 1
        );

        try {
            $apires = $api->SetLocation($ar);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo($e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage() . '<br>');
            var_dump($e);
        }

        echo('<br> end.');
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. The permission set is legit (most probably 775) for the `DocumentRoot` recursively
2. Ensure that

   ```
   <Directory /your/document/root>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```

Comment: @SayedKamalAdinModaresi have you change the permission set to your .php files ?

Comment: i set the permission to 755 and also 777 but nothing change

Comment: @SayedKamalAdinModaresi change all to 777